# c# / 2D Graphics / DrawRectangle size beheviour

Tags: c#, .net, drawing2d

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Pen p = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, 3, 3, 89, 30);
}
```

Why does this code produce a 90px width  / 31px height box? i.e one pixel bigger than requested.
BTW: FillRectangle works fine.

Comment: That's GDI+'s infamous off-by-one bug.  I gave up on it in utter frustration back in 2001 after trying to work around it for a week.  Murder when you need to translate/rescale.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that it is because the command defines the inside size of the rectangle and draws the border around that.

Comment: By your reasoning, it should have been +2px insted. (1px for each side) and the whole "defined rectangle" left as it is.

Comment: True, I had not thought of that.